# DoubleClick use Kotlin programmatically face issue val cannot reassigned

Tags: kotlin, double-click-advertising

I integrate doubleclick to my android app by follow  [link](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/banner)

```
val adView = PublisherAdView(this)
adView.adSize = AdSize.BANNER
adView.adUnitId = "/6499/example/banner"
```

But I faced error `val cannot be reassigned` as below, please help me how to fix it
[image]

Comment: You don't need those `!!` operators. The value will never be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Share for someone face same problem
After researching, I saw `adsize` only delegate for `getAdSize` so I use this code instead

```
adView!!.setAdSizes(AdSize.BANNER)
```